# How could apply CSS property on class and element specific at same time with SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

As shown underneath, there are two (**div** & **span**) HTML element having same class (**content** ), but on **span** only, I want add color property. How it will be done in SCSS?

```css
.content {
  padding-left: 30px;
  span#{&} {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

Please help.

Comment: Just add a separate rule for `span.content { color: red; }`.

Comment: Is it possible like this syntax? .container-color {
  background: #000;
  &.font-size {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use speudo class `:is`,

```
.content {
  padding-left: 30px;
  &:is(span) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `@at-root` which allows advanced nesting: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/at-root

```
.content {
  padding-left: 30px;
  
  @at-root span#{&} {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

compiles into

```
.content {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
span.content {
  color: red;
}
```